# Why my code refuse to compare the generated hashes

Tags: c, cryptography, cs50

I am working on crack assignment from cs50. I am planing to start with comparison hashes from 1 character password but it doesn't work at all.

In the code below `string` is a typedef for `char*` in `<cs50.h>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Enter the hash code as a single argument\n");
        return 1;
    }

    string salt = get_string("Imput the salt\n");

    string hash = crypt(argv[1], salt);

    string key[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S"};

    if(strlen(argv[1]) == 1)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<18; i++)
        {
            string cypher = crypt(key[i], salt);

            int comp = strcmp(cypher, hash);

            if(comp == 0)
            {
                printf("%s", key[i]);
            }

            else
                printf("unmatch\n");

        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program with salt 12 and code to be hashed and checked as A which is in my array i recive this message:

```
~/pset2/ $ ./crack1 A

Imput the salt:
12



ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
```

In other words the program prints me entire array instead of printing just the character witch match with the hash.

Comment: Is this C or C++? I haven't really followed the standards since I have gave up my C/C++ habit many years ago, but does C have a `string` type now?

Comment: @JamesKPolk it's a typedef in cs50.h.

Comment: @JamesKPolk No, C does not have a string type. The cs50 teachers [still think it is a good idea to confuse their students by saying that a `string` is a string pointer](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/163).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `crypt` function returns a pointer to a static data buffer.  That means that each time you call `crypt` that static data changes, so `hash` points to a buffer that changes on each iteration.  This is why it matches every time.

You need to make a copy of the string returned on the first call to `crypt`.  Then you can compare that against subsequent calls.

```
string hash = strdup(crypt(argv[1], salt));
```

Comment: Good catch, I'm surprised I can't find a previous question like this.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to solve this without using pointers. I haven t studied this yet and this problem shouldn't include them. I don t want the solution to this just a tiny guide. Thank you for answer!

Comment: @Criticalll You already are using pointers.  The `string` typedef hides that fact.

Comment: `crypt` returns at most 21 bytes (including terminating null character). Create an array of 21 bytes and copy the result into it.

Comment: This is why using `string` is bad practice. You are obscuring the fact that its value is a pointer to something rather than the contents of a string. Actually, it's worse than that -- you are affirmatively misleading people into thinking its value is a string.

Comment: @dbush string hash has the same value of argv all the time. Did you mean to duplicate string cypher which is included in for function?

Comment: @Criticalll it does not have the value of `argv[1]`.  It has the return value of `crypt`.  That is why you need to duplicate that one.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Do you want to [join me in making the typedef go away](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/163)? Maybe it helps if they get some more voices on this topic.